# Detecting changes in float

Tags: swift, delegates, floating-point

Is there any way in which I can detect a change in float in swift? I also want to conduct a method when there is a change in float. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Have you looked at KVO, notifications, didSet / willSet methods? And I assume that you mean "a floating point number" which btw. is not one of the five nouns that my dictionary shows when you look up the noun "float".

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to swift and did not know that whenever I type in the word "float" on xcode, it actually meant "a floating point number." DidSet method worked for me, so thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solution is implement didSet:

```
var myFloat: Float? {
    didSet {
        println("change occuterd \(test)")
    }
}
```

You will see a log in the console every time the value changed, or try willSet to see a value before change.

You can also use KVO and notification.

Comment: @Riks Consider accepting the answer if it was the answer you asked for.